# SqlCommand insertion query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert, sql-insert

I have to execute a query of insertion in my c# code

```
connexion = new SqlConnection(connexionString);
             connexion.Open();
            List<int> liste = client.GetIDFichiers(1210);
            int a = 2;
            foreach (int idfichier in liste)
            {
                a++;
                using (connexion)
                {
                  using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO REL_Fab3DLotFichier_Fichier3D (IDREL_Fab3DLotFichier_Fichier3D,IDFichier3D,IDFab3DLotFichier,CreePar,CreeLe,ModifiePar,DateMaj,EstActif) VALUES (" + a + "," + idfichier + "," + 17965 + "," + null + "," + null + "," + null + "," + null + "," + 1 + ")", connexion))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }

                    }
                }

            }
```

The insertion isn't working and i don't know why. the selection and delete queries worked fine. Only when i try to insert values a syntaxic error appears.

- what is the syntax error?
- How can i fix it?

Comment: Please specify the error...

Comment: show you table schema

Comment: Wow where should I start!  For a start you are concatenating ints with strings and with nulls.  Secondly...consider parameterized queries.

Comment: Always use parameterized queries. It will prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the values you are passing may be string/varchar objects and you aren't wrapping them with quotes:

```
new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO REL_Fab3DLotFichier_Fichier3D (IDREL_Fab3DLotFichier_Fichier3D,IDFichier3D) VALUES ('" + a + "', '" + idfichier + "')", connexion);
```

Really, as AVD suggested, you should use parameterisation, which is less prone to injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the syntax error? and How can i fix it?

Yes. Use parameterized SQL statement.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (Column1,Column2) VALUES (@value1,@value2)";
using(SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection))
{
 sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@value1",SqlDbType.Varchar,20).Value = varName1;
 sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@value2",SqlDbType.Varchar,20).Value = DBNull.Value;
 ...
 }
```

Try to include not null fields to prepare INSERT SQL.

```
sql=@"INSERT INTO REL_Fab3DLotFichier_Fichier3D 
                (IDREL_Fab3DLotFichier_Fichier3D,
                 IDFichier3D,
                 IDFab3DLotFichier,
                 DateMaj,EstActif) 
     VALUES 
                (@IDREL_Fab3DLotFichier_Fichier3D,
                 @IDFichier3D,
                 @IDFab3DLotFichier,
                 @DateMaj,@EstActif)";
```

Answer (score 0):

please enclose your string values in single quotes like below

```
 New SqlCommand("insert into Type(TypeName,TypeOrder,CategoryID) values ('" + txtType1.Text + "','" + txtOrder.Text + "','" + ViewState("CatID").ToString() + "')", con)
```